# Replacing specific character around all strings in a string

Tags: php, string, replace

I am trying to find an efficient way to do this in php.

I want to format an output of a string with some character. Here's what I want to accomplish as an example:

- '''I am bold'''
- ''I am Italic''
- '''''I am both bold and italic'''''

For those who know wiki, I take my example from there. :)

Is there a pre-made function in php or do we need to loop in the string to accomplish this? I don't mind a reference to a similar question. I haven't been able to find it.

regards,

Comment: what do you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do something like this:

```
$opened = false;
while(($pos = strpos($string, "'''''")) !== false){
    if($opened) $string = substr($string, 0, $pos) . "</b>" . substr($string, $pos + 5);
    else $string = substr($string, 0, $pos) . "<b>" . substr($string, $pos + 5);
    $opened = !$opened;
}
if($opened) $string .= "</b>";
```

And this further on for every time one less `'`.